# Laravel redirect to local referer after login

Tags: laravel, redirect, authentication

Trying to make redirect this way:

in LoginController add function redirectPath

```
public function redirectPath()
    {
        if (method_exists($this, 'redirectTo')) {
            return $this->redirectTo();
        }

        return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
    }
```

and redirectTo()

```
public function redirectTo(){
        return '/dynamic_url';
    }
```

How can I set my '/dynamic_url' to path that I came from

---

If add

`$this->localReferer =  app('Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator')->previous();`

It defines backurl correct, but when I submit login, page reloads and referer changed to '/login'

also tried to set cookie in __construct()

```
use Cookie;
...
Cookie::make('localreferer', $this->localReferer, 60);
```

and this does not create a cookie

Comment: All about redirects: http://laraveldaily.com/all-about-redirects-in-laravel-5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is you can define the hidden field in your existing form and this field will use in your controller for redirection like below.

**Add in your form**

```
{{  Form::hidden('url',URL::previous())  }}
```

**Get in your controller file.**

```
 $url = $request->input('url'); 

 return redirect($url)->with('success', 'Your msg is here');
```

Answer (score -2):

with

```
return redirect()->back();
```

you can go where you come from.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it didnt work for me. 
1. Im on page cars click /login
2. Im on page login (here my backurl = '/cars')
3. After filling fields and submit login my backurl = '/login'
Any case I tried it in my code and get redirect to the main page